# Promise return value and nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I have a function `createOne()` that should try to find a MongoDB document or create it if it cannot be found. In either way, a promise should be returned and the promise resolved with `doc`:

```
var createOne = function(category) {
    var self = this;

    return this.findOne({ slug: category.slug }).exec()
        .then(function(doc) {
            if (!doc) {                    
                return self.create(category); // wait to resolve until document created.
            }
        });
};
```

Both [`findOne().exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) and [`create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) (should) return a promise.

I tried out many different ways such as using Q.fcall, manually creating one with Q.defer() and others, but either the resolve value was missing, or the second `{ slug: 'foo' }` was created as well even though the first already existed(?).

Following is my calling code:

```
var data = [
    { slug: 'foo' },
    { slug: 'bar' },
    { slug: 'foo' } // <- shouldn't be created because of first 'foo'.
];

Q.fcall(function() {
    // [...]
}).then(function() {
    var promises = data.map(function(category) {
        return createOne(category); // <- calls createOne().
    });
    return Q.all(promises);
}).then(function(categories) {
    console.log(categories);
}).done();
```

How can I structure `createOne()` so that `console.log(categories)` returns the documents, whether they are found or created first?

**Edit:** When the collection is empty, only two documents should be created. `{ slug: 'foo' }` only once.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if (!doc)` have an `else` clause that returns `doc` directly?

Comment: a) Is that only pseudo code or does your `.exec()` call already return a promise (with a `.then()` method)? b) How does mongoose signal that no document was found, is it an error or does it pass `null`?

Comment: Yep, that's right, thanks! The return values are ok now :)
I think the second `{ slug: 'foo' }` is created because I call my `createOne()` rapid-fire style, not waiting for the async find/create calls to finish. Could that be?

Comment: @Bergi `exec()` really returns a promise. If no document is found, `doc` is `null`.

Comment: @JohnB.: You mean a race condition where both queries signal that no document is available, and then both create one? Yes, without a transaction management system this can easily happen. Would it be OK if the `promises` where not executed in parallel?

Comment: @Bergi Exactly, because `createOne()` is called for all three category objects almost at the same time through `data.map()`. And with `Q.all()` I only wait for the `createOne()` promises to resolve, but not in between `createOne()` calls.

Comment: @Bergi  Yes, if they where not executed in parallel that would be fine as well. But they should all finish.

Comment: I've switched to using sequential calls to `createOne()`, see http://jsfiddle.net/aCukx/. The thing is my last `console.log` now only has access to the resolve value from the last array iteration. Even with `forEach` I cannot seem to build a combined promise with an array of values such as `Q.all()` would give. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have figured out how to call asynchronous functions sequentially and compose a final array of all their promises (and later resolved values).

My solution is based on a great `array.reduce` example I found in a [comment from kriskowal](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/pull/438#issuecomment-29161866)   on Github.

```
var data = [
    'Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3'
];

function asyncMock(element) {
    console.log('Handle', element);
    return Q.delay(element + ' handled.', 500);
}

var promise = data.reduce(function (results, element) {
    return results.then(function (results) {
        return asyncMock(element).then(function(result) {
            results.push(result);
            return results;
        });
    });
}, Q([]));

promise.then(function(elements) {
    console.log('Finished:', elements);
}).done();
```

You can find a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvu4/